# Java Solving FizzBuzz problem through converting an ArrayList to an array issue

Tags: java, fizzbuzz

So I am trying to solve the FizzBuzz problem in Java by altering a String ArrayList and then returning a string array after converting the aforementioned ArrayList to a String array

Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class FizzBuzz 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 1; i<=100; i++)
        {
            arrList.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <arrList.size(); i++)
        {
            if (Integer.parseInt(arrList.get(i)) % 3 == 0 && Integer.parseInt(arrList.get(i)) % 5 == 0)
            {
                arrList.set(i, "FizzBuzz");
            }
            if (Integer.parseInt(arrList.get(i)) % 3 == 0)
            {
                arrList.set(i, "Fizz");
            }
            if (Integer.parseInt(arrList.get(i)) % 5 == 0)
            {
                arrList.set(i, "Buzz");
            }   
        }

        String[] arr = arrList.toArray(new String[arrList.size()]);
        System.out.println(arr);
    }
  }
```

The error it gives me states:

```
   "Fizz"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at FizzBuzz.main(FizzBuzz.java:23)
```

I understand that this error has something to do with not being able to check whether the string element in the arrayList is a multiple of 3,5,etc but that is why I make use of the Integer.parseInt() method which is why I am confused as to what I am doing incorrectly.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class FizzBuzz 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 1; i<=100; i++)
        {
            arrList.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }

        //problem lies with all the if statements change them to if-else
        for (int i = 0; i <arrList.size(); i++)
        {
            if (Integer.parseInt(arrList.get(i)) % 3 == 0 && Integer.parseInt(arrList.get(i)) % 5 == 0)
            {
                arrList.set(i, "FizzBuzz");
            }
            if (Integer.parseInt(arrList.get(i)) % 3 == 0)
            {
                arrList.set(i, "Fizz");
            }
            if (Integer.parseInt(arrList.get(i)) % 5 == 0)
            {
                arrList.set(i, "Buzz");
            }   
        }
        //this will print the list
        arrList.stream().forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
    }
  }
```

It is because after you change 3 to "Fizz", this will throw an error -> Integer.parseInt("Fizz").
I have added a comment, to change if to if-else.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that after your number 3 enters the if %3 and if %5 it also enters the separate if's for both %3 and %5 and it will basically check if "FizzBuzz" converted to an integer will be %3.

The **solution** is to **transform the if (%3) and if (%5) into else if (%3) and else if (%5)**

Comment: Also the printing at the end is not correct, I think this way you will print the hashcode of that list. I recommend looping through it and printing it one by one.

Comment: Lists stringify to `[item1,item2,...]`, where `item1` is the `.toString()`-ed form of the first item, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

And God created `else`...

You should make it so that when an `if` hits, the `if`(s) following it do not run. Otherwise they would try parsing the freshly replaced string as a number. Practically: write an `else` in front of the second and third `if`s.